# tkinter: How do I make it so if I select an option from a dropdown, it will disable specific Entry boxes?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I got my dropdown contained in a list

```
ITEMS = [
    "Item1",
    "Item2",
    "Item3",
    "Item4",
    "Item5",
]
```

Then I got my code for the drop down:

```
buttvar = StringVar()
buttvar.set(ITEMS[0]

drop = OptionMenu(root, buttvar, *ITEMS)
drop.grid(row="0", column="2", columnspan=2, sticky=W)
```

How would I go about making it so if I select Item 1 from my drop down that it would remove a certain entry box within the UI?

For example, if I click Item 2.

Entry Box 1 and 3 disappear, only allowing the user to enter data into Entry Box 2?

Hope this is clear enough...

Comment: do you want to disable or remove?

Comment: @JacksonPro he seems to clearly state disappearing, so I assume that Entry widget is not visible anymore

Comment: @Matiiss the title states something else

Comment: @JacksonPro oh, didn't notice that, well that creates an interesting situation, however there shouldn't be much difference anyways

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a dictionary of items as key and entries as values. set command parameter to a function. If you want to disable the entries then use `entry['state'] = 'disable'`. If you want to hide the entry use `.pack_forget()` or `.grid_forget()`

Example code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def selected(event):

    for entries in item_dict.values():
         entries.pack_forget()    
  
    item_dict[event].pack()

root = Tk()

ITEMS = [
    "Item1",
    "Item2",
    "Item3",
    "Item4",
    "Item5",
]

item_dict = {}

buttvar = StringVar()
buttvar.set(ITEMS[0])

drop = OptionMenu(root, buttvar, *ITEMS, command = selected)
drop.pack()

for x in ITEMS:
    ent = Entry(root)
    ent.pack()
    item_dict[x] = ent

root.mainloop()
```

Edit:

For what you are trying to achieve you need to add extra entries and use `.pack` to display them when an item is clicked.

This example will display the toppings and bun of the corresponding item when the submit button is clicked.

```py
from tkinter import *

def item_extras():
    
    value = f"{buttvar.get()}"
    for item, ent in extras.items():
        value += f"\n{item}: {ent.get()}"
        
    print(value)

def selected(event):

    for entries in item_dict.values():
         entries.pack_forget()    

    for ent in extras.values():
        ent.pack_forget()
        
    item_dict[event].pack()

    for item, ent in extras.items():
        ent.delete(0,"end")
        ent.insert(0, item)
        ent.pack()
 

root = Tk()

ITEMS = [
    "Item1",
    "Item2",
    "Item3",
    "Item4",
    "Item5",
]

item_dict = {}

topping = Entry(root)
bun = Entry(root)

extras = {"Toppings": topping, "Bun": bun}

buttvar = StringVar()

drop = OptionMenu(root, buttvar, *ITEMS, command = selected)
drop.pack()

for x in ITEMS:
    ent = Entry(root)
    ent.insert(0, x)
    ent.pack()
    item_dict[x] = ent

Button(root, text="Submit", command=item_extras).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry I knew when I had wrote this out that I should have changed the title to be more accurate, but forgot. I want it to hide, not disable.

Anyways, that seems to make sense if I pick Item 1 for box 1 to disappear but how would that work for multiple boxes? If I clicked Item 1, how do I make it so box 3, 4, 7 and 8 disappear? Is there maybe a decent webpage that I could use that'd explain how to make this work using a dictionary over a list?

Comment: @Dexsana if you want to hide it you must use `.pack_forget()` or `.grid_forget()` depending on the layout manager you used. You can simply remove the commented part beside the `entries['state'] = 'disable'` and `item_dict[event]['state'] = 'normal'` to from the above code see how its done

Comment: The way you have it written, if you click Item 2, only 1 box that relates to Item 2 shows up.

How do I make it so it's multiple boxes? Maybe that'd be easier.

Comment: @Dexsana pls try running it. It removes all the other entries other than the selected item. Say you select item1 then all the others are hidden. Try typing something in the entry box to check that. I made an edit now try running it.

Comment: I did try running it.

Comment: @Dexsana what do you mean by "How do I make it so it's multiple boxes?"

Comment: Right now if you click Item 3, only 1 box will appear for Item 3... what if I wanted 3 boxes? How do I make it 3?

Comment: @Dexsana so you want to display all the Entry other than the selected item?

Comment: Yes. 

Let's say I'm trying to make a menu. Item 1 is a hot dog. I'd want an entry box for toppings, bun, type of dog. Etc. Item 2 is a hamburger, I'd want to reuse that entry box for the toppings, bun... etc.

I'd like multiple entry boxes.

Comment: @Dexsana made an edit tell me if that's what you were looking for.